# Objects in space

Tags: forces

If an object is set in space, will it move away from its location?

Say a space station. Without any kind of thrusters, would it stay where it is, or always be moving off location?

Comment: Seems like you're basically asking if gravity exists in space

Answer (score 1):

Here is where it comes down to ones philosophy. Stationary relative to WHAT? If it at a space station around the earth, it should more or less follow the same orbit that the station follows. The space station is in pretty low earth orbit however so it actually feels some atmospheric drag. If this is the case, then the object, due to its cross section, might experience a higher or lower drag, meaning it will fall behind or go ahead of the station.

If we assume the object is within our solar system and at a non-terminal velocity, then it is in orbit around a celestial body. Thi orbit might be circular or very elliptical, but it is there nonetheless.

If we have an object in free space however, we might deem it to be stationary relative to the surrounding space, however, if we view it more macroscopically it is most likely still in orbit around a body such as a star or a planet or any mass in space really.

The parameters for the question are too vague to give one, definitive answer, but i hope my answer answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What is specific to space, as opposed to, for example, atmosphere, is the absence of friction (the vacuum). All fundamental physical forces are still present in space, notably gravity: a space station without thrusters if close to a planet or star will just fall towards that massive object.

In practice, it is difficult (and in most cases not desirable) to have an object put in space be initially at rest with respect to a planet (say Earth) or a star (like the sun). It will have some non-radial velocity component which will make it move away from the planet at the same time as it falls to it; the resulting trajectory is an [orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit).

Now if the space station is far from any massive object, it will still fall along a path depending on far-away stars or even galaxies, what is called a [geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity).